# Separate datetime string for plot

Tags: r, date, time, plot

I have a datetime string like so:

```
> mydatetime
 [1] "2012-01-07 14:53:52 EST" "2012-01-07 07:57:03 EST"
 [3] "2012-01-07 17:42:28 EST" "2012-01-08 10:28:35 EST"
 [5] "2012-01-08 10:37:22 EST" "2012-01-09 08:12:00 EST"
 [7] "2012-01-09 08:11:44 EST" "2012-01-09 17:45:24 EST"
 [9] "2012-01-09 14:28:22 EST" "2012-01-09 13:14:38 EST"
```

I'd like to separate the date and time into separate objects.  I can get date successfully as:

```
> as.Date(mydatetime)
 [1] "2012-01-07" "2012-01-07" "2012-01-07" "2012-01-09" "2012-01-08"
 [6] "2012-01-08" "2012-01-08" "2012-01-09" "2012-01-09" "2012-01-09"
```

How can I extract the time portion?  My goal is to plot date on the y-axis and time on the x-axis, to show a timelime of each day. Seems like the plot function requires special formats, so strings won't work here.  Any recommendations on timeline-esque plotting functions are appreciated as well.  Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Simon's answer below worked for me.  However, I had to pull the date substring from mydatetime first, then use as.Date.

```
date <- as.Date(substr(mydatetime, 0,10))
```

For some reason it was five hours off.  For example, `2012-01-09 19:05:21 EST` would be converted to `2012-01-10`.  My timezone settings seem fine, and putting that string into as.Date directly gave `2012-01-09`.  No problem, I'm happy with this solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways -- either you treat it as a string:

```
time = as.POSIXct(substr(mydatetime, 12,19),format="%H:%M:%S")
plot(time, as.Date(mydatetime))
```

or you compute on the dates:

```
time = .POSIXct(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(mydatetime)) %% 86400)
plot(time, as.Date(mydatetime))
```

There is a subtle difference in the resulting plot ranges.

Comment: I can't get the time to just be HMS. I'm still getting the whole date string:
`as.POSIXct(substr("2016-03-02 16:14:27", 12, 19), format="%H:%M:%S")` yields `"2016-03-16 16:14:27 EDT"` when I want just `16:14:27`